# Updating Custom Adapter Content On Inner-Button Click

Tags: android, adapter, buttonclick

So I'm trying to be able to change the look of a List Item from my Custom Adapter that I made on the fly. I'd like it to change when I click a Button from within the List Item of my Custom Adapter. 
[This is an example of a Custom List Item looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHt0D.png)
When I click on the Button, I want it to perform an action to modify the layout. For example, after clicking Button, I want it to hide another button, or change the text of the button. For some reason, these commands seem to have no effect when clicking them.

My ultimate goal is to be able to resize the List Item on a button click. But as I mentioned, nothing seems to take effect. Setting visibility outside of the onClick method seems to work, but doing it inside doesn't. I know the code is being reached, but I believe it has to do with the adapter not updating, but I have the notifyDataSetChanged method in there. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Here is my Custom Adapter code

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {
Button button, button2;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players) {
    super(context, R.layout.player_expanded, players);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater infater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
    final View customView = infater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);

    button = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button2 = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);   //Doesn't take effect
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return customView;
  }
}
```

And my Custom_List_Item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:focusable="false"  
    android:id="@+id/button"  />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is your buttonGone?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo. Fixed.

Comment: android:focusable="false" remove and try

Comment: @comeback4you changed, ran, no change in results

Comment: check if click event if performed or not. like printing Toast or something.

Comment: did Log.d("adapter", "clickedme"); and prints to monitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try as below:

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {

private static class ViewHolder {
    Button button, button2;
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players) {
super(context, R.layout.player_expanded, players);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
ViewHolder viewHolder; // view lookup cache stored in tag
   if (convertView == null) {
      viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
      LayoutInflater infater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
final View customView = infater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);

viewHolder.button = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button);
viewHolder.button2 = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button2);

viewHolder.button.setTag(position);
viewHolder.button2.setTag(position);
convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
       viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
viewHolder.button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        viewHolder.button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);   //Doesn't take effect
        notifyItemChanged(Integer.valueOf(v.getTag().toString()));
    }
});

return customView;
}
}
```

Comment: More or less this worked. This was the approach I needed to take (using viewHolder). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Calling notifyDataSetChanged() causes ListView to rebuild everything. It will remove its setVisibility gone, call getView() for all the items that are visible.
For that you need one logic and manage Visibility of button.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are making button invisible inside `onClick` and then notifying your adapter.

Now you have wrote `button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` inside your adapter. so whenever your adapter gets notified it will again set visibility of button to visible.

Easy way of doing this is use `SparseBooleanArray`.

```
class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Player> {

    Button button, button2;
    SparseBooleanArray mArray;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Player> players) {
        super(context, R.layout.player_expanded, players);
        mArray = new SparseBooleanArray(lenth of your list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            final View customView = infater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list_item, parent, false);

            button = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button2 = (Button) customView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
        }
        if(mArray.get(position)){
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else if(!mArray.get(position)){
            button2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mArray.put(position, true);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return customView;
    }
}
```

Hopefully this will work for you.